# Python: Request-ID thread-local logging

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

colleagues

Currently, I'm setting up logging in several Python components and have a question about the thread-local logging setup.

So, I have the Request-ID field coming to the component in different ways (Headers for queue messages and Rest calls).
I set up logging formatter with this request ID:
`%(levelname)s: [%(name)s] [%(request_id)s] %(message)s`

This formatter is common for all logs

Each subsequent class in the processing flow creates own logger using 
`logging.getLogger(<class-name>)`

**The question is:**
How can I set the request ID once on thread start (message handler, rest handler) and be sure that it will remain the same in all subsequent calls inside the thread, but other parallel threads, obviously,  will have its own request IDs?

Comment: you could you `Adapter` for that: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information

Comment: I can use an adapter when I create a logger.
So, in all classes where I need logging I have to write 
```logger = MyAdapter(logging.getLogger(), {"request_id": request_id})```
The problem is that all classes must **know** that there is some adapter to use, while I just want to have a transparent setup for logging, just put an additional extra variable once for all loggers (because I'm creating formatter pattern once for all loggers)
Additionally, I have to pass ```request_id``` to all classes (methods) so they can create correct adapter